# Unable to build a unity app with Firebase on Unity 2022.3.11

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

When I tried to build, I got this error and could not build.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user_name\App_name\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin$ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.ApplicationAndroidComponentsExtensionImplCompat.
         > Cannot have abstract method AndroidComponentsExtension.registerSourceType().
```

What error is this and how can it be resolved?

I'm not sure of the details. If anyone has successfully built a unity app with Firebase, it would be great to know which settings to adjust and how.

I think it would be a more detailed version of the question

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
```

Comment: What platform are you building on and what platform are you building for?

Are you able to run the game in the editor?

If you have not, please consider trying out the steps listed in [Debugging the Game Build, Install and Run Process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/build-debug-guide) and the [EDM4U Usage Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/troubleshooting-faq.md#edm4u-usage-troubleshooting-guide)

Comment: Why do you think this is Firebase related?

Answer (score 0):

Self resolved.
I found when I looked up manually modifying the gradle to deploy Firebase that these were all wrong, and if I did nothing (no modifications to the gradle) I was able to deploy.